# Filter a timeseries with some predefined dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code :

```
close[close['Datetime'].isin(datefilter)]   #Only date in the range
close1='Close' ; start='12/18/2015 00:00:00';
end='3/1/2016 00:00:00'; freq='1d0h00min';
datefilter= pd.date_range(start=start, end=end,   freq= freq).values
```

But, strangely, some columns are given back with Nan:

```
  Datetime   ENTA   KITE   BSTC   SAGE   AGEN  MGNX  ESPR   FPRX      
  2015-12-18  31.73  63.38  16.34  56.88  12.24   NaN   NaN  38.72      
  2015-12-21  32.04  63.60  16.26  56.75  12.18   NaN   NaN  42.52
```

Just wondering the reasons, and how can we remedy ?

Original :

```
            Datetime   ENTA   KITE   BSTC   SAGE   AGEN  MGNX  ESPR   FPRX  

       0    2013-03-21  17.18   29.0    20.75   30.1    11.52  11.52  38.72


       1    2013-03-22  16.81   30.53   21.25   30.0    11.64  11.52  39.42

       2    2013-03-25  16.83   32.15   20.8    27.59   11.7   11.52  42.52

       3    2013-03-26  17.09   29.55   20.6    27.5    11.76  11.52  11.52
```

EDIT:

it seems related to the datetime hh:mm:ss filtering.

Comment: I'm assuming the `NaN` aren't in the original dataframe?  Can you post a sample of the original of the original so we can repeat?

Comment: Just Edited with putting the original data. Wondering if my code is correct ?

Comment: the data you pasted above has missing values.  I'm assuming that's where your `Nan`s are coming from.  Each row only has 6 values but you have 10 columns

Comment: There are not missing (it's the copy and paste). Obviously, all data are there otherwise question would be non-sense...

Comment: Okay...then can you adjust the copy and paste so that I have the full original data?  This still doesn't help me repeat your issue

Comment: Dont think this is related to the data, but rather with the datetime in hour min seconde. It seems filtering in min and display can be different.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the data either, I'm just trying to get a reproduce-able example...